# How can we set ajax response to struts2 select using Dojo

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, dojo

I'm working on dojo and Struts2, facing one issue.
Dynamically making ajax call and getting response in JSON format and contain many key value pairs, want to set this response to Strut2 select

Could you please help on this issue, how can i fix this issue?

Struts select Tag:

```
<s:select id="empindex"  list="#{EmployList}" name="Employ" listKey="key" listValue = "label"  emptyOption="true" value="%{destination.key.toString()}" />
```

Ajax:

```
employs.ajax.fireJavaScriptRequest("getEmploys.action", {}, function(details) { 
     dojo.byId("empindex").innerHTML=details;
     });
```

JSON Response:

```
{"Employs":[{"label":"Test1","key":123},{"label":"Test2","key":345},{"label":"Test3","key":567}],"identifier":"key"}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, is the json result not working for you for some reason?

Comment: I'm getting JSON response and able to see from firebug. but not sure how we can set this json object to select tag

Comment: You'd need to write some JavaScript if you're interacting with a plain HTML S2 tag.

Comment: Added Code to my orignal post

Comment: You're setting the innerHTML to a JSON object? Not sure that makes any sense.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Yes correct,but i couldn't find any solution. could you please help me on this.

Comment: Once you have a JSON object then you interact with the component like any other; there are a zillion tutorials on setting a select's options from JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56963/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-and-dave-newton).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Edited**

In your jsp file you can use `jquery` to populate combo box.

**Code Updated**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadEmplDropDown();
function loadEmplDropDown() {

            $.getJSON("getEmploys.action", function(details) {
                //convert json in html and set html
                var options = '<option value="' + "--Select--" + '">'
                        + "--Select--" + '</option>';

                for ( var i = 0; i < details.employs.length; i++) {
                    //alert(details.employs[i].key);
                    options += '<option value="' + details.employs[i].key + '">'
                            + details.employs[i].label + '</option>';
                }
                $("select#empindex").html(options);//or dojo.byId("empindex").innerHTML=options;

            });
        }
  </script>
  <s:select id="empindex"  list="#{EmployList}" name="Employ" listKey="key" listValue = "label"  emptyOption="true" value="%{destination.key.toString()}" />
```

**Note:** 
1. Try with Capital E in employs because in your json it is `Employs` instead of `employes`

```
     for ( var i = 0; i < details.Employs.length; i++) {
                    //alert(details.Employs[i].items.key);
                    options += '<option value="' + details.Employs[i].key + '">'
                            + details.Employs[i].label + '</option>';
                }
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Please comment if this does not work for you or you can accept an answer if this answer worked to you.  [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)